# Finding the union of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, set, union

I'm trying to find the Union of two arrays created by the user input.  I keep getting:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at TwoSets.main(TwoSets.java:47)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoSets 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int i, array, choice;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many numbers do you want in each set? ");
    array = input.nextInt();

    int set1[] = new int[array];
    int set2[] = new int[array];
    int set3[] = new int[array*2];

    for(i=0;i<set1.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number from the first set: ");
        set1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

    for(i=0;i<set2.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number from the second set: ");
        set2[i] = input.nextInt();
    } 

    System.out.print("Enter 1 to find Union\n" + "Enter 2 to find Intersection\n" + "Enter 3 to find Difference\n");
    choice = input.nextInt();
```

The code above is initializing and getting user input, which is working fine.  It is the code below that is not functioning.

```
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<array;i++)
        {
            set3[i] = set1[i];
        }

        for(i=array;i<array*2;i++)
        {
            boolean check = Union(set2[i], set3);
            if(check == false)
            {
                set3[i] = set2[i];
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<set3.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(set3[i]);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean Union(int number, int[] array)
{
    for (int i : array )
    {
        if (i == number)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you actually use a Set implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This code goes out of bounds when it tries to check an index position in set2 that is greater than the length of set2.

You'll note that when iterating through array*2 you attempt to send set2[i] to union(). This won't work as soon as i is greater than or equal to set2.length. This is where your error comes from.

```
for(i=array;i<array*2;i++)
        {
            boolean check = Union(set2[i], set3);
            if(check == false)
            {
                set3[i] = set2[i];
            }
        }
```

You only need to iterate through the length-1 of set2 to union in this method.

```
for(i=array;i<array;i++)
    {
        boolean check = Union(set2[i], set3);
        if(check == false)
        {
            set3[i] = set2[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I can see how that would mess it up

Answer (score 1):

The set2 have length of array, but in:

```
for(i=array;i<array*2;i++)
        {
            boolean check = Union(set2[i], set3);
            if(check == false)
            {
                set3[i] = set2[i];
            }
        }
```

you use array*2 in loop.
I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TwoSet {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer [] {1,2,3,4}));
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer [] {3,4,5,6}));
    Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<>();
    set3.addAll(set1);
    set3.addAll(set2);
    set3.forEach((i)->{System.out.println("set3: "+i);});
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is a question for a practical implementation, then you're good. If this is for a school assignment, then it will probably help you zap-scotch-notch.

Comment: I saw this one other threads but I have to use arrays that get user input.  I'm gonna save this for reference use though

Comment: You can keep both yours and this. Just instead of `Arrays.asList(new Integer [] {1,2,3,4})`, use `Arrays.asList(originalSet1)`. Basically feeding your original array that you collected from user input, and let HashSet do all the magic for you. If you are ok using a Set ... you can also use `set1.add(input.nextInt)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of your exception by changing your code as follows

```
     for(i=0; i<array;i++)
    {
        boolean check = Union(set2[i], set3);
        if(check == false)
        {
            set3[i+array] = set2[i];
        }
    }
```

However this will leave gaps where the common elements would be.

You would probably be better doing something like

```
    j= array;
    for(i=0; i<array;i++)
    {
        boolean check = Union(set2[i], set3);
        if(check == false)
        {
            set3[j] = set2[i];
            j++;                
        }
    }
```

Then use array copy to create a new array  of the correct length and copy the populated elements over.

Using a list for set3 would remove the need for the last step.

Using a set for set3 would do it more simply.

Comment: You should mark the correct answer and add any helpful comments to help people who find this question later.